# visual studio load test unable to find assembly error when running remotely

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have written a custom LoadTestPlugin to vary the number of users randomly. When i run this test locally everything works great, but when i deploy it using the controllers and agents, its give me 'Unable to find assembly' error, like its not able to find the assembly in which that plugin is, even though the test and plugin are in the same assembly.

any clues on how to accomplish this ?

many thanks

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem:

Visual Studio have some problems with network and web dll. BradA have a solution to Web Dll (assembly) [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/12/11/visual-studio-project-sample-loading-error-assembly-could-not-be-loaded-and-will-be-ignored-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hresult-0x80131515.aspx). But it didn't solve my problem. I was running a simple hello-world WpfApplication with a TestProject. The HelloWorld was working, but not the TestProject. It told me that the assembly was missing even if the Dll did build. Then I realized that my solution was on a Network drive. **I try to run the solution locally and Voila** ! So Visual Studio 2010 was loading the assembly as not trusted, the same way as a web assembly. So I guess it's not possible to do it on a Network drive...